# Scaling a ruby script by launching multiple processes instead of using threads

Tags: ruby, linux, scaling

I want to increase the throughput of a script which does net I/O (a scraper). Instead of making it multithreaded in ruby (I use the default 1.9.1 interpreter), I want to launch multiple processes. So, is there a system for doing this to where I can track when one finishes to re-launch it again so that I have X number running at any time. ALso some will run with different command args. I was thinking of writing a bash script but it sounds like a potentially bad idea if there already exists a method for doing something like this on linux.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend not forking but instead that you use [EventMachine](http://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine) (and the excellent [em-http-request](http://github.com/igrigorik/em-http-request) if you're doing HTTP). Managing multiple processes can be a bit of a handful, even more so than handling multiple threads, but going down the evented path is, in comparison, much simpler. Since you want to do mostly network IO, which consist mostly of waiting, I think that an evented approach would scale as well, or better than forking or threading. And most importantly: it will require much less code, and it will be more readable.

Even if you decide on running separate processes for each task, EventMachine can help you write the code that manages the subprocesses using, for example, `EventMachine.popen`.

And finally, if you want to do it without EventMachine, read the docs for [IO.popen](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/IO.html#M002242), [Open3.popen](http://www.ensta.fr/~diam/ruby/online/ruby-doc-stdlib/libdoc/open3/rdoc/classes/Open3.html#M001414) and [Open4.popen](http://github.com/ahoward/open4). All do more or less the same thing but give you access to the stdin, stdout, stderr (Open3, Open4), and pid (Open4) of the subprocess.

Answer (score 1):

You can try fork http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Process.html#M003148

You can get the PID in return and see if this process run again or not.

If you want manage IO concurrency. I suggest you to use EventMachine.

Answer (score 0):

You can either

1. implement (or find an equivalent gem) a ThreadPool (ProcessPool, in your case), or
2. prepare an array of all, let's say 1000 tasks to be processed, split it into, say 10 chunks of 100 tasks (10 being the number of parallel processes you want to launch), and launch 10 processes, of which each process right away receives 100 tasks to process. That way you don't need to launch 1000 processes and control that not more than 10 of them work at the same time.